# Jquery slide animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, uislider

Good day!

I am trying to hide and show divs with slide animation.
My code is as follows:

```
<style> 
    div.bigBox
            {
            background-color:white;
            width:100px;
            height:125px;
            overflow:hidden;
            }
            div.try{
            background-color:green;
            width:100px;
            height:125px;
            float: left;
            }
            div.try2{
            background-color:yellow;
            width:100px;
            height:125px;
            }
    }   
  </style> 
  <script language="JavaScript" src="js/jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ui.jquery.com/latest/ui/jquery.effects.core.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ui.jquery.com/latest/ui/jquery.effects.slide.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
    <div class="bigBox">
          <div class="try">
              <p id="haha">CLICK THIS</p>
              <p>This is a demonstration of jQuery SimpleDialog.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="try2">
              <h3 id="test2">CLICK THIS</h3>
              <p>This is a demonstration of jQuery SimpleDialog.</p>
          </div>
    </div>
<script> 
    $('#haha').click(function () {  
      alert("test");
      $('.try').hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
      $('.try2').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
    }); 
</script>
```

The problem is the transition of one box to another. It doesn't flow very smoothly. I want to hide and at the same time show (like tailing the box to be hidden). Please help. Thanks

Comment: Unrelated to the problem: you have an extra closing curly brace right before you close the style tag. Related: Here's a fiddle (jQ 1.7 to make access to jQ UI easier) for anyone taking a stab at it: http://jsfiddle.net/GregP/CV7fd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably a dozen ways to skin this cat, but here's what I did:

- Gave the bigBox position: relative
- Changed the try boxes to use position: absolute so that they stack on top of one another
- Changed the order of the HTML to make sure try (not try2) stays on top; you could do this other ways like with z-index
- Removed overflow: hidden on bigBox and made background transparent, although that shouldn't honestly make a difference
- Changed the CSS to suit my personal style; sorry, it's a semi-OCD thing

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GregP/CV7fd/1/

I didn't methodically test my theory, but I THINK it was the floating that was causing your problem.

No point showing the "switching the order of the .try and .try2 boxes" markup or the JavaScript (which is untouched), but here's the updated CSS:

```
div.bigBox {
  background-color:transparent;
  width:100px;
  height:125px;
  position: relative;
}

.try, .try2{
  width:100px;
  height:125px;
  position: absolute;
}

.try {
  background-color:green; 
}

.try2{
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

(shoot, could've used the width: and height: on bigBox, too. Ah well, you get the point, no need for me to be pedantic!)

Comment: (also FWIW, I thought fading looked neat, too: http://jsfiddle.net/GregP/CV7fd/2/)

Comment: do you have a slider code where i can use the css overflow:hidden;? Because the function of my code above is limited to 2 movable boxes. Tnx

Comment: The overflow: hidden was not a necessary change that I made. I just tested and it's fine with or without. Was easy to test... just visit the fiddle!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered having both elements in a single div (which would be partially visible) and just slide it by changing margins, padding or however you implement it?

Comment: ok I think you'll need another one (wrapper and container), but try adding these CSS rules to it and see what happens: margin-left: -100px; width: 200px;   My idea was to animate these two values if it would work with the other elements on the page.